# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MissingValueException

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to build an android project, but it is showing the following errors:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MissingValueException: Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MissingValueException: Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.

I am using Android version 2020.3.1 (Arctic Fox) and Gradle version 6.8.3. Can someone please suggest to me what should I do to solve it?

Comment: As i seen in error you still not accepted licences. Accept them from terminal first. Using -> # In Windows 
C:\Android\SDK\tools\bin --- Run #then
sdkmanager --licenses

Comment: After running sdkmanager --licenses command, this error is showing -
```
D:\android\sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager --licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156) ...................
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ................

```

Comment: First go to the directory by entering -> "C:\Android\SDK\tools\bin --- Run"  then run -> "sdkmanager --licenses "

Comment: @SakibReza Use JDK 1.8 (Or simply JDK 8) for Android. Replace the JDK in your PATH variable or your gradle.properties file with a JDK 8.